# How to install the admin panel in 1.0

Tags: panel, admin, red5

I'm trying to install it but with no success.
Steps:
1. copied admin.jsp to /red5/webapps/root
2. Pasted all the jars from adminplugin-1.0.zip to /red5/plugins
3. started the server. ERROR:

```
[INFO] [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1fa490e: defining beans [global.clientRegistry,global.serviceInvoker,global.mappingStrategy,global.context,global.handler,global.scope,red5.scopeResolver]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@be49e0
[WARN] [main] org.red5.server.ContextLoader - Context destroy failed for: default.context
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'default.context' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:529) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
```

So what's the procedure, i can't find it. I've been trying for the whole month to accomplish this!

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the adminpanel does work with the red5 version you are using. Where did you download adminpanel from? I guess you might contact the mailing list to find the author of the adminpanel.

You can see the last commits / changes of the admin application have been done in 2008:
https://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/#svn%2Fflash%2Ftrunk%2Fadmin

I don't think that it is actively maintained at the moment, so it is actually your job to get it running and debug it if you need it.

Comment: Thanks. That didn't answer my question but it helped me to understand how underdocumented this project is...

BTW, i've got it running now with v0.9.1, by copying the jars of the adminpanel zip into the lib folder, then running admin.jsp.

Comment: They currently have issues with Spammers and DoD attacks. That is why the wiki is down for example.

Comment: I would recommend using the latest Red5 1.0. xx or even a nightly builds as there are fixes and updates almost weekly.