# how to undeploy red5 RTMP application on linux?

Tags: tomcat, video-streaming, rtmp, red5, live-streaming

I am able to create red5 RTMP application and able to stream successfully. But after completion of streaming. I am not able to undeploy/uninstall the application :(. I tried deleting application directory under /, but it didn't make any difference. Can anybody explain me the process of undeploying/uninstalling red5 RTMP application. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483962/how-to-install-the-admin-panel-in-1-0

Answer (score 1):

Stop the server, delete your app directory under webapps, delete the work directory, and then restart the server.

Comment: Cant it  be undeployed without restarting the server. Because i dont want to disturb already running applications.

Comment: You can remove it using jmx without a restart, but it will reload if you restart the server.

Comment: Are there any listener classes which i can configure to monitor and undeploy rtmp application. ??  Like war deployer listener.

Comment: You can watch the spring events

Comment: Thank you mondain. Let me explore few more Api and i will update here.